# mysql query to find rows having only single specific sub-category against any category (in group by data)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table with name users. SQL returns following result

```
select user_id, vegetarian, count(*) from users group by user_id, vegetarian;
```

[Current SQL Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSaRz.png)

```
user_id   vegetarian      count(*)
2         1               15
3         0               131
3         1               6
4         1               6
5         0               113
5         1               7
6         1               6
7         0               107
7         1               11
```

[Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4DqZ.png)
My required output is:

```
user_id   vegetarian      count(*)
2         1               15
4         1               6
6         1               6
```

Kindly help me for SQL query to get my required output.

Kind Regards

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT user_id, 1 vegetarian, COUNT(*) 
FROM users 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING NOT SUM(NOT vegetarian);
```

`NOT vegetarian` converts 0 to 1 and backward. Hence `SUM()` calculates the amount of rows which are not vegetarians. And `HAVING NOT SUM()` removes the rows where this sum is above zero.

Comment: 1 vegetarian - a typo? I think should just be vegetarian?

Comment: @P.Salmon No. We select only rows where `vegetarian` value is 1. So it doesn't matter does we extract the value or return the constant - but the last variant is less expensive.